# In "Living Witness," what happened after the doctor was deactivated and nine Kyrian ships attacked?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

The *Voyager*'s story from the doctor ends with this:

> EMH: Computer, freeze programme. A tragic, needless death, but as you
>   can see, Voyager was not responsible. After Tedran was killed, Voyager
>   was attacked by nine Kyrian ships. My programme was disabled, most
>   likely when they stole my backup module. The next thing I knew, I was
>   standing next to this gentleman seven centuries later.

What happened after that? The [next episode](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/tv/star_trek_voyager/s04/e07) plot summary seems to be unrelated.

Comment: Your question is addressed in the dupe. In short, the Voyager was in and out of Vaskan space in a week or two, then carried on its merry way

Answer (score 0):

Well, clearly Voyager left after mostly fighting off the attack.  Voyager never took actually permanent damage from anything.  We were never shown that because the story is told from the point of view of the backup EMH, but we know from the rest of the series that Voyager did manage to get away.

Comment: No future references, or side stories? It's just like District 9 or alien covenant but a little less interesting.

Comment: The Kyrians don't even have a Memory Beta entry.